# How to demonstrate all the TCP Socket States

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I was trying to observe a simple java echo server & client program in runtime on laptop using Ubuntu OS.To understand whats happening behind the scene, I ran the server client & used this command

```
   sudo netstat -pant 10007

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name

tcp6       0      0 :::10007                :::*                    LISTEN      3551/java          
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:35459         127.0.0.1:10007         ESTABLISHED 3570/java       
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:10007         127.0.0.1:35459         ESTABLISHED 3551/java
```

So, we can see that a passive server(loop back) is in LISTEN state and after accepting a client(127.0.0.1.35459) socket creates a new TCP connection with active server (127.0.0.1.10007) in ESTABLISHED state.
However, we know that there are several TCP Socket states such as:SYN_SEND, SYN_RECEIVED, ESTABLISHED, LISTEN, FIN_WAIT_1, TIMED_WAIT, CLOSE_WAIT, FIN_WAIT_2, LAST_ACK, CLOSED etc. So, I was in confusion about other states, whether the program is skipping these socket states or not.

I want to see all the TCP socket states to understand the entire socket sate transition scenario. So where I am doing wrong? did I gave wrong command?  or missing any code modification? Am I lacking any network tools ? what went wrong in my step by step process?

So, How to demonstrate  **all** the TCP Socket States?

Here is the server code:

```
import java.net.*; 
import java.io.*; 

public class EchoServer 
{ 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
   { 
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null; 

    try { 
         serverSocket = new ServerSocket(10007); 
        } 
    catch (IOException e) 
        { 
         System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 10007."); 
         System.exit(1); 
        } 

    Socket clientSocket = null; 
    System.out.println ("Waiting for connection.....");

    try { 
         clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); 
        } 
    catch (IOException e) 
        { 
         System.err.println("Accept failed."); 
         System.exit(1); 
        } 

    System.out.println ("Connection successful");
    System.out.println ("Waiting for input.....");

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), 
                                      true); 
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( 
            new InputStreamReader( clientSocket.getInputStream())); 

    String inputLine; 

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        { 
         System.out.println ("Server: " + inputLine); 
         out.println(inputLine); 

         if (inputLine.equals("Bye.")) 
             break; 
        } 

    out.close(); 
    in.close(); 
    clientSocket.close(); 
    serverSocket.close(); 
   } 
}
```

and Here is the client code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class EchoClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String serverHostname = new String ("127.0.0.1");

        if (args.length > 0)
           serverHostname = args[0];
        System.out.println ("Attemping to connect to host " +
        serverHostname + " on port 10007.");

        Socket echoSocket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {

            echoSocket = new Socket(serverHostname, 10007);
            out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                        echoSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + serverHostname);
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for "
                               + "the connection to: " + serverHostname);
            System.exit(1);
        }

    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(
                                   new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String userInput;

        System.out.print ("input: ");
    while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println(userInput);
        System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
            System.out.print ("input: ");
    }

    out.close();
    in.close();
    stdIn.close();
    echoSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd have to be quick, or run over a link with very low latency. If the network is functioning correctly, SYN-SENT and SYN-RECEIVED will transition to ESTABLISHED within a second, and the same applies to several of the closing stages.

Comment: You need to slow the network connection down to something like 10bytes/second using some kind of throttling tool and you'll see all the states. I suspect things are just happening too quickly for you to observe all the states.

Comment: I can't understand.Can you be more specific: any clear codes or guide lines or similar links.

Comment: You don't understand what exactly? You've had two  comments, both clearly expressed.

Comment: I understand what comments says BUT how make it slow? what commands needed or codes needed to make it slow?

Comment: Even with a slowed down network, the idea of trying to observe "all states" by watching a program isn't really good. Consider: If you don't see a state, what is the consequence? Is the network still too fast? Or is the state never reached? - Only looking at the code or a spec will tell you for sure.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is, that the OS will take care of the states. You can't simply controll L4 protocol from Java. If you wanted to do that, you would have to implement your own TCP stack on linux RAW sockets (maybe there is already an implementation, haven't looked).

So, having OS take care of the states and using loopback for testing, your states will have lifetime of a few microseconds. (Actually I believe modern linux will even skip some of those when both ends are at the same machine and there is no actual network involved.) I'd say that trying to see the states through netstat has little to no value in comprehending how TCP works.

I suggest, you to take a look at the [Wikipedia TCP page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Protocol_operation) instead. It describes all the states well and has nice diagram depicting the state transitions as well.

If you want to see what happens 'on the wire', I suggest you try either tcpdump. `tcpdump -n -i lo port 10007` (see manpage for further usage, more detailed output, etc.), or GUI app Wireshark. Wireshark will be probably better option for you, since it dissects the packets really well and explains pretty much every bit.

(Actually tcpdump can be used to capture packets to file - using `-w file` flag, and then opened in Wireshark later.)

Comment: it is now clear to me after your comment. but still is it possible to retrieve tcp packets(i guess tcp packets contains:SYN flag, ACK flag , FIN  flag etc) on a specific socket connection & port, then i can easily get some alternative explanation about whats going on behind.So, do you know any commands (e.g: netstat etc ) ?

Comment: @user5005768 I updated the answer ... hope it helps.